# Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: mysqli, codeigniter-3, php7, apache2

Estoy utilizando CodeIgniter con Apache 2.4, ya revise mi archivo de php.ini y no tiene comentada la linea de `extension=php_mysqli.dll`, ya de igual manera revise que tengo instalada la libreria y realmente no sé cual es el error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
>
> Filename:
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\planningproject\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 135
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\planningproject\application\controllers\Proyectos.php
>   Line: 7 Function: database
>
> File: C:\Apache24\htdocs\planningproject\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: ¿Qué versión de php tienes?

Comment: Tengo instalada la version 7.2.11

Comment: Prueba con php 7.1

Comment: Sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje

Comment: Bienvenida. Por favor coloca el código al que se refieren los mensajes. Hace referencia a la línea `7` del archivo `Proyectos.php` y a un `require_once` que hay en la línea `315` de `index.php`. Otra cosa que puede estar ocurriendo es que haya restricciones en el sistema. Otra opción sería intentar usar PDO en vez de mysqli. Revisa si [esto funciona](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161856/5587982) y si no, [prueba esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44250315/5587982).

Answer (score 1):

Proyectos.php

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));



}
```

index.php

```
  require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '-',
    'username' => '-',
    'password' => '-',
    'database' => 'pl',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a la comunidad, para que se te pueda brindar ayuda, es necesario colocar el código en TEXTO y NO en imagen, edita tu pregunta.